# I want a linked duplicate to keep form change but have separate material

Tags: linked-data

My goal is to have two meshes that deform together as linked duplicate, but that each have it's own material.

I tried to make single user material only but it does not work. It just makes both meshes to have the same new material.

Either I manage to have both form and material being linked, or both unlinked.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143434/different-materials-with-linked-objects